# Nuget package for System.Web.Hosting

Tags: c#, nuget, system.web

In a legacy project I am working on, there is a using directive:

```
using System.Web.Hosting
```

I supposed, that the nuget package name should be `System.Web` and tried to install it via Nuget.

But there's no such package.

[image: no package]

Question: where can I get this package and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know that `System.Web` is not available for `.netstandard` projects. And my project is a `.netstandard` project (migrating from .net framework).

This is the reason why the System.Web package is not available. I think it would be far more better, if unavailable packages would be displayed, but with message, that they are not availble for a particular reason.

Otherwise users spend much time to finding out the reason of such issue.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but not speaking in the right forum. I would vote for your answer but it does not answer the question of the topic.

I would advise you to post your question directly to [Microsoft forums](https://developer.microsoft.com) and there people can vote, so Microsoft has visibility on the matter and actually take some changes towards it.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Web` is not a nuget-package, it's a framework reference and `System.Web.Hosting` is one of the namespaces located in `System.Web`

Depending on your project-type, whether it's the old or new format, you have to do the following

For old format:

1. Locate the project and collapse it
2. Right click on "References" and press on "Add reference"
3. In the window that pops choose the menu on the left named "Assemblies" and then search for "System.Web"

For new format:

1. Right click on the project and press on "Edit"
2. Find an existing `<ItemGroup>` or add a new one
3. Add this line `<Reference Include="System.Web" />`

Comment: Thank you. As far as I understand the problem related to my project type. My project has `.netstandard` project type. And System.Web is not available for netstandard projects.

Comment: That is true but it's still not a Nuget package.

Comment: Thank you, I will know that now. Thanks :)